WhatsApp Template Media Header Handler vs Media ID
I have created whatsapp template using header as image using Resumable API and attached the hash like this.
{
        "h": "2:c2FtcGxl..."
}

Now to send this template i need to either attach an image url or media ID using media API like below.
{
        "type": "header",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "type": "image",
            "image": {
              "link": "http(s)://URL"
            }
          }
        ]
      },

So As per the doc https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/send-message-templates#media-based we need to send media_id or URL.
How can i use previously uploaded hash to send media without uploading second time.
